# Test whether a Metropolis-Hastings chain is "sufficiently near" equilibrium using the autocorrelation function

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and $\mathcal E$-measurable and $$Y_n:=f(X_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N_0.$$

In my scenario, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is the chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. I would like to check numerically how close the chain is at equilibirum when the current iteration is $n\in\mathbb N$. I've read that this can be checked by the "autocorrelation function", but I'm unsure how precisely.

I know that if $\mathcal L(X_0)$ (the distribution of $X_0$ under $\operatorname P$) is invariant with respect to the transition kernel $\kappa$ of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, then $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ has asymptotic variance $$\sigma^2(f):=\operatorname{Var}_{\mathcal L(X_0)}[f]\tau(f),$$ where $$\tau(f):=1+2\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\operatorname{Corr}[Y_0,Y_n].$$

Now it is unclear to me, what precisely I need to check numerically. We can define $$\gamma_{m,\:n}:=\operatorname{Cov}[Y_m,Y_n]$$ for $m,n\in\mathbb N_0$. If we've generated $Y_0,\ldots,Y_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N_0$ so far, then I've seen (see, for example, https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Advanced_Statistics/Time_Series_Analysis_(Aue)/2%3A_The_Estimation_of_Mean_and_Covariances/2.2%3A_Estimation_of_the_Autocovariance_Function) that the following estimate is used for $h\in\mathbb N_0$ and $\gamma_{0,\:h}$: $$\frac1{n-h+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-h}(Y_m-E_n)(Y_{m+h}-E_n)\tag1,$$ where $$E_n:=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^nY_i.$$

It seeems like this is assuming stationarity of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ (i.e. that $\mathcal L(X_0)$ is already the invariant distribution). However, this will not be the case in my computer simulation. So, I guess I need to discard the first $b\in\mathbb N_0$ samples, but the details are still unclear to me; especially how I actually need to program a suitable stopping criterion.

Comment: if you're not set on this particular approach, the most common way to test MCMC chain convergence is probably the Gelman Rubin statistic https://blog.stata.com/2016/05/26/gelman-rubin-convergence-diagnostic-using-multiple-chains/

Comment: There's no really good way of checking this, because you could be sampling in one part of the distribution that is only connected through an incredibly low density region with the rest of the distribution that you never get to. In practice, monitoring Rhat (as mentioned), divergent transitions, effective sample size and so on is what is done and except for in awkward situations like the one I described it tends to work.